# Producing a picture of DFA that recognizes given regexps

Tags: python, regex, compiler-construction, dfa

Is there a tool that will accept a list of regexps and produce a picture of the minimal DFA that will recognize these regexps, each into its corresponding final state?

It should look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOGRS.jpg
The picture is taken from Stanford compilers class, probably made by the teacher himself.
This FA handles a subset of Pascal tokens, the numbered/lettered states are final states.

I don't need the actual code for the DFA, just the picture of how it looks.

If there is no such tool, how would I go about making this kind of graphs? Is there some kind of specialized python GUI library that will do that?

Comment: I will try to write that in future. +1 for your link and for your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't remember if it does *exactly* what you want, but [JFLAP](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/) Will let you enter a regular expression and then convert to a NFA/DFA.